# Export Job Failed : while trying to sqoop csv from HDFS to MySql (date format issue)

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

The Mapper Jobs are being stopped due to some runtime exception.The basic thing is that the date format in csv file is 'dd-Mon-yy' and is different from the MySql 'yyyy-mm-dd' format.This results in an Exception in Mapper Job where the date is converted to java.sql.Date

Is there any means by which we can sqoop it to mysql?

The command given was:

```
sqoop export --connect "jdbc:mysql://myhost/databasename" --table <tablename> --username <Myusername> -P --export-dir '<directory name>'
```

This sqoop Job Failed

Comment: I would use Spark rather than Sqoop if your data is inconsistent

Comment: You could sqooq the data to mysql but that column not in date format. Try as a String format to a stage table and then transform the data to a date format and lastly load the data into the master table. Or as @OneCricketeer said use Spark to transform and load the data into mysql.